# Does Ellen Corby star in Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory (1971)?

Tags: casting, charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory

I'm new here but I've used other Stack Exchange sites.

Fairly recently, as a family, we watched the 1971 Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory. When Charlie finds the golden ticket, he gets surrounded by people in the street.

In the commotion, a person shouts out:

> "Let me see it"

Then the same voice says:

> "Do you see what he's got?"

Just search for: 'Charlie finds the golden ticket' to see the scene.

I'm pretty good at recognising actors from other productions when I see them, usually it's the voice of the person that triggers me. I hear Ellen Corby's voice as the person that says the lines above, we've watched many episodes of The Walton's and it caught my attention immediately.

After searching through the cast of the film and Ellen Corby's filmography, I cannot see that it is her.

Is this Ellen Corby? Or some other actress?

Comment: The chances of this being potentially possible must be balanced against how much the film would need a bit-part actor of extensive experience & therefore decent commandable price so much that they would pay to ship them from the US to Germany for what was likely only a one-day scene in an uncredited role. I'd bet the odds are slim. The get-out may be if the ADR was done back in the US, so the voices & the people on-screen are not the same. Chances of finding that data are negligible from back then. You'd need personal anecdote.

Comment: That's a good point, I had no idea it was filmed in Germany. As you said I guess the voice over could have been done in the US.

Comment: I'm going to drop that in as an answer, because I do think it's as close as may be possible to discover.

Comment: I don't understand how this is "off-topic." How is the author supposed to improve this question so it's on-topic with so little guidance?

Comment: @Chaim How can this be improved? It's a question about a trivial detail of a fifty year old movie. If the information they're after hasn't surfaced in that time, why would it become available now? Ellen Corby died 20 years ago, the director ten years ago,...

Comment: @BCdotWEB I don't think I can improve on the question. I don't understand the urge to close a question just because an answer may seem to be impossible to find. I guess I was hoping someone had another source of information that I had not tried.

Comment: @JackPettinger The question wasn't closed because an answer couldn't be found. The question was closed because it was a) trivia (=  questions that do not add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie/TV-show) and b) an identification question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB It seems to me that all across the Stack Exchanges there is a growing tendency to close questions because the close-voters just don't know the answer and are happy to remain ignorant. The age of the movie does not normally count against questions here. We cannot conclude that the information hasn't surfaced just because we don't know it. How could OP or anyone else know whether this information has surfaced except by asking here and allowing people to answer, or, as I sometimes do, to refrain from answering because I don't know the answer?

Comment: @BCdotWEB The cast of a film is trivia? Questions are normally closed because they don’t add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie or show? Your top post is about what the cast knew when shooting Alien, eight years after the making of Willie Wonka. Is that eight-year difference the important difference, or your belief that the information is necessary in order to understand or appreciate Alien? I think that the standards that you're invoking in this chat are rarely honored and would be detrimental to the site if they were.

Comment: @Chaim Please read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask). As I have already pointed out, there are **two** reasons why this question is off-topic. Even if you disagree with this question being trivial (and it is), it would still be an ID question and those are off-topic.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Hmn... the first link mentions "Identifying a movie or TV series," and the other two links don't contain "ident" at all. So Jack's question is off-topic because asking whether an actor appears in a film is "Identifying a movie or TV series"?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Is Jack's question much more trivial than, say, "Who made the painting of a man and his two dogs in a boat?"

Comment: Before you two continue this ad nauseam... it took 5 votes to close this. It would take another 5 to re-open it. Any discussion as to why or why not 5 people did vote to close yet no-one has yet voted to reopen is not going to be resolved in comments. (I didn't vote either way)

Answer (score 2):

[IMDB Full cast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067992/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)

According to IMDB Full cast page - there is no Ellen Corby in the cast.

[IMDB Ellen Corby](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0179289/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)

And, according to Ellen Corbys IMDB page, She was not in the film.

Comment: The OP already stated that the available information had been checked.

Answer (score 1):

*from my own comment. I think this may be the closest it's actually possible to discover.*

The chances of this being potentially possible must be balanced against how much the film would need a bit-part actor of extensive experience & therefore decent commandable price so much that they would pay to ship them from the US to Germany for what was likely only a one-day scene in an uncredited role.
I'd bet the odds are slim.

The get-out may be if the ADR (additional dialog recording) was done back in the US, so the voices & the people we see on-screen are not the same. The chances of finding that data are negligible from back then. You'd need personal anecdote.